# covariant return type for default method

Tags: java, default-method, covariant-return-types

I can override a method with covariant return type, but is it possible to override a **default** method with covariant return type? In the following example, I would like to override getFirstLeg without rewriting the default method, but Java does not allow that. I also do not want to make Animal a generic interface because there may be many parameters and Animal is used in a lot of places.

```
interface Leg {
}

interface Animal {
    List<? extends Leg> getLegs();

    default Leg getFirstLeg() {
        return getLegs().get(0);
    }
}

abstract class AnimalImpl<T extends Leg> implements Animal {
    private List<T> legs;

    @Override
    public List<T> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }
}

interface DuckLeg extends Leg {
}

interface Duck extends Animal {
    @Override
    List<? extends DuckLeg> getLegs(); //covariant return type

    @Override
    DuckLeg getFirstLeg(); //I do not want to rewrite this method
}

class DuckImpl extends AnimalImpl<DuckLeg> implements Duck {
    //Error: java: DuckImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getFirstLeg() in Duck
}
```

Update: The following code compiles, but the new problem is that Duck is no longer an Animal.

```
interface Leg {
}

interface AnimalGeneric<T extends Leg> {
    List<? extends T> getLegs();

    default T getFirstLeg() {
        return getLegs().get(0);
    }
}

abstract class AnimalImpl<T extends Leg> implements AnimalGeneric<T> {
    private List<T> legs;

    @Override
    public List<T> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }
}

interface Animal extends AnimalGeneric<Leg> {
    //empty
}

interface BirdLeg extends Leg {
}

interface BirdGeneric<T extends BirdLeg> extends AnimalGeneric<T> {
}

class BirdImpl<T extends BirdLeg> extends AnimalImpl<T> implements BirdGeneric<T> {
}

interface Bird extends BirdGeneric<BirdLeg> {
    //empty
}

interface DuckLeg extends BirdLeg {
}

class DuckImpl extends BirdImpl<DuckLeg> implements Duck {
}

interface Duck extends BirdGeneric<DuckLeg> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java does have covariant return types for inherited methods.  But the problem here isn't the fact that `getFirstLeg` is a `default` method, it's that Java's generics are not covariant; they're invariant.  I.e. A `List<DuckLeg>` is not a `List<? extends Leg>`, even if a `DuckLeg` is a `Leg`.

But you can get around this by making the `Animal` interface generic, so that the type parameter can change based on the sub-interface(s).

```
interface Animal<T extends Leg> {
    List<T> getLegs();

    default T getFirstLeg() {
        return getLegs().get(0);
    }
}
```

Then `Duck` has a type parameter also, but does not need to override anything anymore.  The type argument `DuckLeg` is assigned to `T`.

```
interface Duck extends Animal<DuckLeg> {
    // able to remove the override of getLegs
    //@Override
    //List<DuckLeg> getLegs(); //covariant return type

    // able to remove the override of getFirstLeg
    //@Override
    //DuckLeg getFirstLeg(); //I do not want to rewrite this method
}
```

Then your `DuckImpl` class will inherit everything properly, and you won't get the "not abstract and does not override abstract method" error.

Of course with an empty declaration of `Duck`, you may not need it at all.  Just have `DuckImpl` implement `Animal<DuckLeg>`.

```
class DuckImpl extends AnimalImpl<DuckLeg> implements Animal<DuckLeg> {

}
```

Comment: Please see the last sentence in my post. I have concerns about making Animal (or any other widely used interface) generic because if we would like to change a parameter we will have to change a lot of places.

Comment: Although a List<DuckLeg> is not a List<? extends Leg>, shouldn't a List<? extends DuckLeg> be a List<? extends Leg>?

Comment: Making `Animal` generic is the only way I see to solve the problem precisely because Java generics are invariant.  Also, A `List<? extends DuckLeg>` cannot be a `List<? extends Leg>`, because the wildcards represent specific yet unknown types.  The `List<? extends DuckLeg>` could represent a `List<DuckLeg>` while the `List<? extends Leg>` could represent a `List<TurkeyLeg>`.  Because of the possibility of mismatches, the compiler must disallow covariant generics with wildcards.

Comment: If that is the case, why can I use List<? extends DuckLeg> getLegs() to override List<? extends Leg> getLegs()?

Answer (score 0):

If you want covariance, type the `Leg`. You can then delete most of your code.

This compiles:

```
interface Leg {
}

interface Animal<T extends Leg> {
    List<T> getLegs();

    default T getFirstLeg() {
        return getLegs().get(0);
    }
}

abstract class AnimalImpl<T extends Leg> implements Animal<T> {
    private List<T> legs;

    @Override
    public List<T> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }
}

interface DuckLeg extends Leg {
}

interface Duck extends Animal<DuckLeg> {
}

class DuckImpl extends AnimalImpl<DuckLeg> implements Duck {
    // no errors
}
```

Comment: Please see the last sentence in my post. I have concerns about making Animal (or any other widely used interface) generic because if we would like to change a parameter we will have to change a lot of places.